# Where can I learn more about relativisations of P and NP?

Tags: algorithm

A landmark paper entitled "Relativisations of the P =? NP Question" by Theodore Baker, John Gill, and Robert Solovay was published in the SIAM Journal of Computing Vol.4, No.4, December 1975.

It talks about the P vs. NP problem and introduces methods of relativisations.  I have the paper, but I'd like to know more about testing an algorithm to see if it is relativisable.  Where can I find more resources on this?

There is more information.  A recent attempt was made at proving that P is not equal to NP, and it involved trying to avoid relativisations.  I was wondering if someone might have more information on this so that I may be able to learn more on the techniques involved.  For example, a link to the paper would be good.

Again, any help on this topic would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Interesting and useful question, but to me it looks like this one would be more at home in http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [this blog](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/08/01/pnp-relativisation-and-multiple-choice-exams/) (from Terry Tao) interesting on the subject.